# Getting PHP error/warnings when using CodeIgniter 2 to send email

Tags: php, codeigniter-2, sendmail, ion-auth

I'm using **Ion Auth** and trying to implement the forgotten password feature which relies upon an email being sent from CI.  My LAMP server is on a shared cPanel account and uses `sendmail`.  However, I have the ability to over-ride any PHP settings with my own `php.ini` file in the `public_html` directory.

As per the [CodeIgniter 2 documentation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/email.html) for configuring email sending, I have done the following...

1)  created a file called located at `application/config/email.php`

2)  `email.php` contains this code:

```php
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
/*
| -------------------------------------------------------------------
| EMAIL SENDING SETTINGS
| -------------------------------------------------------------------
*/

$config['protocol'] = 'sendmail';

/* End of file email.php */
/* Location: ./application/config/email.php */
```

3)  The in the `application/config/ion_auth.php` file, I set this value to `TRUE`

```php
$config['use_ci_email'] = TRUE;
```

The email is successfully sent, but I get a variety of PHP Error Warnings on all pages.

These appear on all pages, sometimes two or three times in a row:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: date() [function.date]: It is not safe to rely on the
>   system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the
>   date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In
>   case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this
>   warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We
>   selected 'America/New_York' for 'EST/-5.0/no DST' instead
>
> Filename: libraries/Email.php
>
> Line Number: 704
>
> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: date() [function.date]: It is not safe to rely on the
>   system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the
>   date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In
>   case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this
>   warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We
>   selected 'America/New_York' for 'EST/-5.0/no DST' instead
>
> Filename: libraries/Email.php
>
> Line Number: 709

In addition to the above, these two also show up after the forgotten password form is submitted:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at
>   /home/username/codeigniter/system/core/Exceptions.php:185)
>
> Filename: libraries/Session.php
>
> Line Number: 675
>
> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at
>   /home/username/codeigniter/system/core/Exceptions.php:185)
>
> Filename: helpers/url_helper.php
>
> Line Number: 540

I'm not sure why I would be getting these Error Warnings or how else I am supposed to configure my email sending options.  I don't see any other email sending options in the documentation that is related to these particular Warning Messages.  When I remove my `config/email.php` file AND set Ion Auth's `use_ci_email` to `FALSE`, the Error Warnings go away.

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: +1 Why not post it now as an answer? It's a valid method in SO.

Comment: @Tivie, I know.  Two reasons, 1.  How I fixed it might be unusual and 2.  I want to first see how others would do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should have never created my own custom `php.ini` file.  I constructed it improperly and I placed it in the wrong location.  Despite thinking that I knew the problem when I posted the question, I did not.  My bad `php.ini` file was the root source of this issue all along.

Answer (score 4):

This has nothing to do with CI.  PHP requires that you set the setting `date.timezone`.

See http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.configuration.php#ini.date.timezone

Comment: Greg is correct, also the headers already sent errors are being caused by the date.timezone error being outputted to browser, fix the date.timezone PHP directive and it will fix all the errors.

Comment: According to my `phpinfo.php` page, both the `local` and `master` value for `date.timezone` is set to `America/New_York`.  That value is valid, AFAIK.  Also, what about the other error/warnings I have?

Comment: _"This has nothing to do with CI"_ ~ that may or may not be true, but I only see these errors when CI contains `config/email.php` or when Ion Auth is configured to use CI's email function.

Comment: @Sparky672 Recheck the default timezone in the php.ini file. 

Or maybe some 3rd party script is reseting the timezone. Check the timezone prior to launching the mailer script, with date_default_timezone_get()

Comment: @Tivie, There are no time zone settings within `public_html/php.ini` and since this is shared hosting, I have no access to the `php.ini` for the whole server.  `phpinfo.php` also shows `Default timezone` as `America/New_York`.

Comment: @Sparky672 what about in the .htaccess? If the script is complaining about the timezone and the timezone is correctly set in php_info() then something must be different in the two places.

Comment: @Tivie, There is nothing setup in `.htaccess` with regards to PHP or time zone.  I'm thinking I need to post the actual solution sooner rather than later.  Because I too would really like to know how what I did caused time zone errors.

Comment: @Tivie, I've posted my answer... sorry for the delay.

Answer (score 2):

One thing it's odd is the location of php.ini. I mean, in public_html folder means php.ini might be readable by the world which might not be the best of ideas.

Anyway, one way to troubleshoot this is creating a test.php file in your public_html folder with only `phpinfo(INFO_CONFIGURATION);` and check the settings (like include_path or allow_url_fopen). Then create a php.ini in the same folder (with some settings like allow_url_fopen) and see if anything has changed in `phpinfo(INFO_CONFIGURATION)`.

My guess is that either:

- public_html/**.htaccess** file is telling Apache to read php settings from a php.ini file located at the public_html folder.
- **your hosting provider has cpanel with mod_suphp (very common). suPHP, by default, allows each user to set their own php.ini as they see fit. It overrides sustem's php.ini.**

---

See [this link](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.per-user.php) and [this one](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php)

---

In any case, you can tweak php.ini settings without overriding it completely by either:

- Set settings in your accounts root .htaccess
- create a script that reads and applies settings

Keep in mind that only runtime settings that are marked as PHP_INI_ALL can be overriden this way. [See this link for more info on settings mode](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.modes.php) and [this for a comprehensive list of changeable php.ini settings](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php)

---

The first way is very straight forward:

.htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
  php_value date.timezone "Europe/Lisbon"
  php_admin_flag engine on
</IfModule>
```

The second uses a custom phpini.file

1. Create a file called `myphpini.ini` (or something) and place your custom settings there.
2. Then create file called `configphp.php` (or something) that reads `myphpini.ini`
3. Include `configphp.php` at the top of your scripts (or in CI2 bootstrap file)

---

**configphp.php**

```
$config = parse_ini_file('myphpini.ini);
foreach ($config as $key => $val) {
    print 'before->' . ini_get($key) . '<br/>';
    ini_set($key, $val);
    print 'after->' . ini_get($key) . '<br/>';
}
```

keep us posted on how it turned out

Comment: I should verify, verify, verify before I open my big mouth.  Refactoring my posted answer.

Comment: I made an assumption which apparently was incorrect.  I assumed that deleting my entire `php.ini` file which only contained one thing, `allow_url_fopen = off` is equivalent to just removing the line... apparently it's not.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. So what was happening was that `public_html/php.ini` was overriding the systems php.ini. That's actually very interesting, although that's probably something specific to your webhosting server.

Comment: See the edits on my answer.  I am still not fully understanding what happened here.  I thought that if I had a custom `php.ini`, that only those items would be over-written... instead, a default like `date.timezone` goes bye-bye unless it's specifically re-defined.  Makes me not want to have a custom `php.ini`.

Comment: The location of my custom `php.ini` was my idea, experimenting, and done out of total ignorance. I like your suggestions and will try them out tomorrow.

Comment: Strangely, the time zone changes I put into my `.htaccess` file do not seem to work according to the `phpinfo.php` page.